# How to search post by another post meta value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In My wordpress setup I have created 2 custom post type

1.) Agents (A1,B2,C3)

2.) Property (P1, P2, P3)

2.1) Property have a taxonomy "City" e.g. NY, CA

2.2) Property have a meta called "Agent", where I assign each property to a agent like "P1" have agent "A1"

Now I want to search Agents by name and city type.

e.g. search Name: "A1"
            city: "NY"

how can I complete it with wp_query

```
if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'agent',
        's' => $_POST['search'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
}
```

currently its only searching by agent name how can I include city filter which is part of another post type ?

Comment: Agents,Property is set taxonomy right ?

Comment: agents and property are custom post type